# Cant see view details button in xcode

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, provisioning-profile

I see a message in visual studio when try to build my iOS project in xamarin.
No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities.  until now I have used free provisioning but now when I try to go to **Xcode-- preferences I see my account but cant see View details button. anybody have an idea why??**

when I try to build my Ios project in Xamarin I get Error No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities.

[image: signing dialog]

[image: "Accounts" settings]

Comment: You have to go to **Manage certificat** to see your certificat.

Comment: I see my certificate on manage certificate but when I try to build my Xamarin Ios project I cant because I get message "No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities." alought I can see in Manage certificate that I have one

Comment: Have you double check that you got the right certificat for the current build setting e.g Development certificat for Debug > IPhone|Debug? And double check that certificat is for the right app ID? Check your app ID in info.plist and check the app ID for your certificat.

Comment: Have you downloaded all profiles?

Comment: I am  having the same issue. I cannot see the View Details button at all. Has this changed in the recent version of XCode 8?

Comment: This is very frustrating. All the instructions, including the official one from Apple keep talking about the `View Details` button yet it's nowhere to be found, and I'm stuck at `no ios signing identities match the specified provisioning profile` even though I use `Automatic Provisioning`

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is a duplicate from this one:
[Create provisioning profile on XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592050/create-provisioning-profile-on-xcode/44592685#44592685)

I think it's normal that you don't see anymore the details button. **Since XCode version 8.?, provisioning profiles are automatically managed** and you can't see the full list anymore.

- You can only click "Download All certificates". I presume you clicked on it.
- So that make me think, something is not configured correctly with your certificate. Double check everything on your apple developer portal.
- Then in your application, the package name must be the same as the AppID indicated in your provisioning profile. Also check the 'expires' field of your provisioning profile to see if it still valid.

Hope this helps.