# Create provisioning profile on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to debug an app (Xamarin.Forms) on my iPhone. I already have Visual Studio on my Windows PC, on which I'm writing the app, and Visual Studio and Xcode on my Mac. I registered the iPhone on my developer account too.

However, it seems like I also need a provisioning profile. But the walkthroughs I've seen have screen unlike the current Xcode. When I click on Preferences - accounts, I see my account, but there's nowhere to add a provisioning profile.

(Does the iPhone need to be signed in with the same Apple ID as the one on the Mac, the one for which I have a developer account?)

How am I supposed to add that?

Comment: From XCode v.8.x, provisionning profiles are managed automatically by XCode... So you don't see the full list. I presume you can only see a "Download All Profiles" button (under Preferences/Accounts menu). Click on it, then In Visual Studio iOS project's properties, your provisionning profile should appear.

Comment: @Julien Do you mean on the Windows VS? (I would actually like to connect the iPhone to it instead of to the Mac, if possible.) Where do I see it there?

Comment: Both VS Mac & Windows (if your Windows VS is connected to your MAC). Connect to your MAC from Windows as mentionned here: [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) -> screenshots may be old...

Comment: @Julien Thanks. It's working with no need to do anything, as you said. You can transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: ok it's done, tanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Xcode 8.x, **provisioning profiles are managed automatically** by Xcode… So you don't see the full list. I presume you can only see a "Download All Profiles" button (under Preferences/Accounts menu). Click on it, then In Visual Studio iOS project's properties, your provisioning profile should appear in both VS Mac & Windows (if your Windows VS is connected to your MAC).

Connect to your Mac from Windows as mentioned here: [Connecting to your Mac](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) -> doc screenshots may be old...

Answer (score 1):

Open your project in Xcode and Go to `Select Project file -> Select Target -> Select Generate tap`

Under `Sigin` category -> Check the `Automatic manage signing`

- It will list down the list of configured developer account.
- Choose your account
- Everything else done by Xcode on behalf of you.
- Xcode will create a provisioning profile in your developer account
  with the Bundle identifier, which you mentioned in `Identity` tap `Bundle identifier`

**Update**

In Xcode 11.*

Automatic signing option is available in `Project -> Select Target -> Signing & Capabilities` section.

Comment: My project is on Visual Studio, on my Windows PC. (I edited the question to be clear about this point, now.)

Comment: I don't see 'project setting' how do you get to that?